# scala var args caseclasses

Tags: scala, variadic-functions

how to test for the length of a var arg parameter for a contructor.

I am defining a case class polygon which takes in a sequence of points, I want to make sure that the no of points is atleast 5 usinga require clause.

```
case class Point(x: Int, y: Int)
case class Polygon(points: Point*)  {
// require(point >= 3) }
```

Answer (score 6):

How about this?:

```
 case class Point(x: Int, y: Int)
 case class Polygon(a: Point, b: Point, c: Point, d: Point, e: Point, other: Point*)  {
  def points = Vector(a,b,c,d,e) ++ other
}
```

Then:

```
val p1 = Point(1,1)
val p2 = Point(2,1)
val p3 = Point(3,1)
val p4 = Point(4,1)
val p5 = Point(5,1)
val p6 = Point(6,1)
val p7 = Point(7,1)

val polygon5 = Polygon(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5)
println(polygon5.points)
// Vector(Point(1,1), Point(2,1), Point(3,1), Point(4,1), Point(5,1))

val polygon7 = Polygon(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7)
println(polygon7.points)
// Vector(Point(1,1), Point(2,1), Point(3,1), Point(4,1), Point(5,1), Point(6,1), Point(7,1))

Polygon(p1,p2,p3,p4)  // error: not enough arguments for method apply
```

Comment: This is a much better way to accomplish this.  Move the requirement into the type system.

Comment: I hope his next req is not gonna be "a vector with an even amount of points", or "a vector with at least 42 points".

Answer (score 4):

Moving this requirement to compile time by making the class take in 5 `Point` arguments and then a `Point*` variadic argument is usually going to be your best bet (as shown by dhg's answer).

If you want to use `require` instead, it is quite simple:

```
case class Polygon(points: Point*)  {
    require(points.length >= 5, "Must have at least 5 points") 
}
```